# Installing WeMo Wi-Fi Dimmer Switch - Lights not turning on

Tags: electrical, dimmer-switch, light

I have attempted to install my WeMo switch; however, it does not seem to want to work. Before I contact Belkin or my superintendent, I wanted to make sure that it is WeMo that is broken, and not my brain.

My living room light switch, once removed has the following wires:
[image]

All wire labels are what I THINK they are, not necessarily what they really are.
But the way I labelled them, is the only way it makes sense? Cause at one point I accidentally started controlling my fridge with the light switch.

So based on that diagram, I wired my WeMo Dimmer switch accordingly. Neutral to white,  Line to brown, Load to beige, and ground... well none of the switches in my apartment have ground. So I let that be.
[image]

The switch gets powered correctly (white light,  and then blue). I even set it up on the wifi. The fridge stays powered on (yay); however, the switch does not turn the lights on and off. Does not matter how many times I press the button. Won't dim. won't turn on.

The lighbulbs I am using are dimmable LED - https://www.lowes.ca/products/view.aspx?sku=12467830.

Before I go over to belkin, I wanted to see if perhaps I did something obviously wrong.

**EDIT:**
At this point I've tested the following:

- Controlling the switch from the app would cause the relay click sound, the switch would appear as if it turned on, but the lights remain off.
- I've tried this with a single LED bulb, a single incandescent bulb, and a mix of both.
- With the original switch connected, in the ON position and with the breaker ON, (aka the lights were shining) I've used non-contact voltage tester and probed an empty bulb socket. This results in continuous high-pitch beeping sound [(48V-1000V AC)](https://data.kleintools.com/sites/all/product_assets/documents/instructions/klein/NCVT2_Instructions.pdf)

  I have then taken my WeMo switch, connected it to the exact same wires + a neutral, and with the breaker ON and WeMo "ON" (the lights weren't shining, this is my issue here) I probed the bulb socket, and there was no light or noise from the tester. This to me indicated that my wiring should be correct (as it was consistent with the original switch + 1 neutral wire, the relay clicks, but no power is sent to the light fixture.

Comment: Does the app or switch display show that it's turning on and off?  Does it make a sound when you turn it on or off?  I have a non-dimmer WeMo switch and you can obviously hear the relay click when it turns on and off.

Comment: @JPhi1618 That's a good point about checking the app to see if it reacts to the switch being physically pressed. I know that when I was running a "dimming test" on the app, the switch would light up appropriately So it works from app to switch. I'll check the switch to app once I get home. There is certainly an audible click when I press the switch button whether  on the app or physically. That's why I am at a loss. Either m lighbulbs are bad (but why?) or there is something funky going on with the WeMo itself :/

Comment: If you're comfortable doing it, you could check voltage of the switch when it's operating, or check voltage at one of the LED bulb sockets to see if it is getting power.  Try at "full on" and get some results before trying to dim anything.  If it's clicking and being controlled by the app it seems like its at least partially working.

Comment: What load are you switching (I.e. how many watts? And what type?) Sometimes loads can be too small (some smart switches have a minimum wattage, I don't know about WeMo in particular tho).  Another thing that happens less with products today than a few years ago, but is a possibility--some LED drivers and some electronic dimmers just don't like each other.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Not very comfortable in checking the voltage, BUT with a regular switch connected and on, I stuck a thing that checks for electricity into an empty bulb socket and it beeped the same as when touching a wall outlet (or the line wire). I did the same test with WeMo switch connected and on - and it didn't detect any electricity at the bulb socket... Despite the relay(?) clicking in the switch, it seems it isn't sending power the right way.

Comment: @Tyson I didn't understand any of that.. sorry... But I did try this with just a single incandescent bulb to make sure its not the amount of bulbs or the bulb type. Same results, sadly.

Comment: Unless you’ve somehow misunderstood the wire colors or what wire goes where, sounds like something might be wrong with the switch.  Double check the documentation just in case.

Comment: I'm very confused as to why you have those colors.  Is this installation in conduit, or multiconductor cable?  Are you sure you aren't mistaking a bare ground wire for "beige"?

Comment: i vote for mis-wired if the relay clicks and nothing happens. the odds of a failure between the terminal/wire and relay are minuscule on a factory-tested device like that...

Comment: @Harper Not sure what is a conduit or a multiconductor cable, but absolutely positive, it's actually just all black wires, but covered in different colour cloth like stuff. All other switches in apartment when it took a look at them, have just 2 black wires. no ground, no neutral. Just 2 black wires.

Comment: @dandavis I really want it to be just mis-wiring; however, there are only 3 wires required - hard to mis-wire that. I am certain that I connected neutral wire correctly (because they seem to be the only properly positioned and coloured wires, heh). As for line and load, if I swap them - the WeMo just doesn't work. Connecting them correctly gets me a "functioning" switch. Just to make sure, I left the fridge wire unconnected, and as expected the fridge was in fact off.

Comment: If you replace it with a plain switch (obviously the plain switch does not take neutral) -- does it work normally, as expected, doesn't switch off the fridge, etc.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your drawing you essentially have it wired “backwards” or at best you are “switching” the fridge. Where is the light you are trying to switch in that drawing.

Line = power coming in
Load = power going out to the device you want to control.

The switch is in between, either connecting or interrupting the flow, therefore, turning on or off the device.

Not sure what the tan box in your drawing between the line wire and fridge represents. It would be unusual for there to be a switch for the fridge. If you are representing that you have “tapped” into that wire to gain power (line) then the load wire from the Wemo needs to connected to the wire that goes to the light you want to control