# How to check if light is "Power Through Fixture"?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, dimmer-switch, light

This is related to my other question [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/130957/installing-wemo-wi-fi-dimmer-switch-lights-not-turning-on).

I just learned of the "power through fixture" concept and it seems that WeMo dimmer switch isn't compatible with it.

I want to believe that what I have in my apartment is NOT power through fixture. But is there any way for me to check if it is?

Comment: Do you have a link that explains what you mean by "power through fixture"?

Comment: Also, what country are you in? I noticed your last question has a brown wire, so I'm thinking you're not in the US...

Comment: that's when you need to use a tungsten bulb (or other medium-heavy load) to power a dimmer/lighted switch/motion detector/dusk-to-dawn and other power-needed "switches" that don't need a neutral. Since the Wemo needs a neutral, you can't parasitically power it like that, which is a good thing anyway: those devices have compat issues with lots of low-power bulbs.

Comment: @JPhi1618 Soutern Ontario in Canada. The power through fixture from what I understand is this: http://www.howtowirealightswitch.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/2-way-switch-power-via-light.jpg

Comment: @dandavis, Ok, I have seen and used that (called by different names), but the OP's other question really makes it look like he has a good neutral connection in the switch box (neutral coming in _and_ leaving).  But then again, I don't really know what all those colors are used for in Canada land.

Comment: the way you determine this is to open the switch box and see if there a neutral available. if the building was built after 1980 or so, likely (if not shoddy), if built after 2009, it has them for sure.

Comment: oh, and if you have a wemo working, you must have a neutral to be powering it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the thing  you're referring to is called a **switch loop**.

You can find out if you have a switch loop by opening up the switch, pop off hte cover plate and pull the switch out a bit.

If you see **one cable** coming into the box with two wires (white and black), and both go to the switch itself (as well as ground if present), that is a switch loop.

If you see one cable, but it has black, white and red wires -- and black and red go to the switch and white is capped off and connected to nothing -- that is also a **switch loop**, however it complies with current code, and that white wire is the neutral wire the smart switch is looking for.

If you see one cable with black-white-red, and all three go to the switch, see "3-way switches" below.

If you see **two cables** coming into the box, and the whites from each cable are wire-nutted or spliced to each other in the back of the box... and one wire from each cable goes to the switch (aside from grounds)... that is **power at the switch**.  That configuration is friendly to the use of smart switches.  The white wires bundled together are the neutral, and they are not "spare", they are in-use as part of the circuit. The smart switch's neutral can be added to these.

---

If you see three wires (other than ground) going to 3-4 different terminals on the switch, and 1-2 of those terminal screws are black...  that's a different thing, that's a **3-way switch**. That is more complicated.  But as far as smart switches, you have more options if you have that nice 3-way cable with its red wire.